# Configure JBoss to work in parent first mode

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I'd like to configure Jboss to run my application in Parent-first mode i.e.:

if a class exist in server/default/lib then load it from there, if not try to find it in web-inf/lib of the deployed application.

How can I configure JBoss to work in this mode? 
as far as I understand my option are only

- to set the application isolation true
  or false
- to set the parent delegation
  true or false

(i.e 4 options)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming you are on JBoss later then 3.2.x
You need to set java2ParentDelegation=true.

Here is full description of classloaders hierarchy of JBoss:
    http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossClassLoadingUseCases
Your case matches case 4.

Also, more information here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingconfiguration